# How can I manually remove ReSharper?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

My IT department insists on being in control and installing a bunch of stuff I don't want or use, including ReSharper... how can I permanently disable ReSharper?

I can uninstall it, but it comes back within a few days.
I can disable it, but it still changes some settings (I can tell when it's installed).

What config files in Visual Studio (2010) does it change, so I can manually remove it?

Comment: Why do you not want to use Resharper? If it's due to performance issues then you may want to request a newer version of Resharper (you don't mention what version you are using) or a better workstation.

Answer (score 1):

In visual studio, go to `Tools`->`Options...`->`Resharper` and click the `Suspend Now` button.

It would be a good idea to let your IT department know that you don't want it as they could pass the license to someone else who needs it). They should also be able to exclude you from getting it installed again.